# Incorrect output for Binary Search with strings

Tags: python

I have a typical Binary Search algorithm implementation:

```
def binarySearch(arr, element):
    first = 0
    last = len(arr) - 1
    while first <= last:
        i = (first + last) // 2
        if arr[i] == element:
            return 'Found at position: {}'.format(i)
        elif arr[i] > element:
            last = i - 1
        elif arr[i] < element:
            first = i + 1
```

The test data is as follows:

```
arr = ['0006', '000e', '000f', '0023', '002a', '002E1627', '0032A542', '0037']
```

When I make a call to the `binarySearch()` function as follows:

```
element = '002E1627'
print (binarySearch(arr, element))
```

I get the output as:

```
Found at position: 5
```

However, with the following input:

```
element = '002a'
print (binarySearch(arr, element))
```

I get the output as:

```
None
```

What is the reason behind this output?

The expected output for the second case is: `Found at position: 4`.

Comment: Your input list isn't sorted.

Comment: Your data must be sorted for binary search to work. Yours is not (`002a` should go after `002E1627`).

Comment: is this supposed to be hex rather than strings?

Comment: The data given to me is in string format. I did consider whether the format was causing an issue with the search.

Comment: your test `arr` is all 4 or 8 chrs in length, withe leading `0`, and appears to hex.  if you are working with 16 and 32 bit addresses or ints it would be useful to know.  provide the specs you were given, and you may get better answers in return.  same a bit odd to mix lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that binary search works only with sorted arrays/lists.

Since the character `a` comes after the character `E` (Lower case are always after uppercase letters), then your list isn't sorted at all.

The list should be:

```
arr = ['0006', '000e', '000f', '0023', '002E1627', '002a', '0032A542', '0037']
```

Then you'll get your desired output

Comment: So, we sort based on the ASCII values?

Comment: I recall it is ASCII for python 2.x, and Unicode for 3.0 onwards, but in any case (Unicode or ASCII) lowercase comes after uppercase

Comment: not ideal to sort.  especially each invocation, if OP eventually has a huge list.  better to fold into a single case.

Answer (score 1):

just convert to a single case:

```
def binarySearch(arr, element):
    first = 0
    last = len(arr) - 1
    while first <= last:
        i = (first + last) // 2
        if arr[i].upper() == element.upper():
            return 'Found at position: {}'.format(i)
        elif arr[i].upper() > element.upper():
            last = i - 1
        elif arr[i].upper() < element.upper():
            first = i + 1

element = '002a'
print (binarySearch(arr, element))

Found at position: 4
```

Comment: This solution, while works, is not always applicable. There are cases where the lower/upper case matters

Comment: the code coould be made more efficient, especially if you could single case the `arr` once and for all.  liikewise, single case `element` just once per call to `binarySearch`

Comment: @Zionsof it works for the OP, real world use cases are divided between 'upper before lower' and 'folded'.  a rule to resolve ties between identical spellings differing only by case would also be needed.  should be determined by the requirements, not the collocating sequence of any particulr programming language.

Comment: @ShpielMeister The data set in reality is an array with 100,000+ elements. Do you think it's better to convert all entries to lower-case?

Comment: depends on how many times it will be used.   more importantly, what does the data represent?  as @Zionof mentioned case can be important.  to answer your question, it seems reasonable in this case to convert the array all to one case.